# error: bundling: UnableToResolveError: Unable to resolve module react/lib/ReactComponentTreeHook

Tags: react-native

Why? Why is react looking here? I have another test android project and it also does not have react package located there, yet it runs perfectly. Why is this one looking here? The only difference is I first did setup a directory below.  In MyProject/App  is where i did the init. I then moved the index.js files and package.json a level up to top level directory. I want to know the WHY of this error!

Here is the error:

```
error: bundling: UnableToResolveError: Unable to resolve module
```

`react/lib/ReactComponentTreeHook` from  `/Users/Admin/Projects/MyProject/node_modules/react-  native/Libraries/Performance/Systrace.js`:
     Module does not exist in the   module map or in these directories:
      /Users/Admin/Projects/MyProject/node_modules/react- native/node_modules/react/lib
    ,   /Users/Admin/Projects/MyProject/node_modules/react/lib

```
This might be related to https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4968
To resolve try the following:
  1. Clear watchman watches: `watchman watch-del-all`.
  2. Delete the `node_modules` folder: `rm -rf node_modules && npm install`.
```

3. Reset packager cache: `rm -fr $TMPDIR/react-*` or `npm start --reset-cach

All these steps I have tried. They don't fix it. I will probably do another init a level above but still I want to know whey it's looking there. Is there a module map being setup somewhere incorrectly? Where do I look for this?

UPDATE: After doing init properly in the root directory of the app I now get something else:

Loading dependency graph, done.
    error: bundling: UnableToResolveError: Unable to resolve module `react/lib/ReactDebugCurrentFrame` from `/Users/Admin/Projects/MyProjectRoot/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/src/renderers/shared/stack/reconciler/ReactCompositeComponent.js`: Module does not exist in the module map or in these directories:

This leads to suggestions that you need alpha version of react to go along with latest react:
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/13017

But doing this does not work. It just leads back to the same issue I had to begin with about ReactComponentTreeHook.

Again, same suggestions about how to fix it. rm -rf node_modules followed by npm install!  But I also did a npm install --save on react react-native.  I think I need some response from react-native team on how to properly interpret this kind of error. What's going on here?

Answer (score 3):

Xcode 8.2 still occur same error. Three lines bellow fixed it for me :)
Downgrade react(16.0.0-alpha.12 -> 16.0.0-alpha.6) & react-native(0.45.0 -> 0.44.0)
**rm -rf node_modules/react** 
**npm i react@16.0.0-alpha.6** -S
**npm i react-native@0.44.0** -S
Then run **react-native run-ios** 
Hope this help.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the npm init, npm install --save react -react-native does not install the correct versions.  What you need to do is look at the version of react inside package.json   In my case it was an alpha.

So right now need to do:

```
npm install --save react@16.0.0-alpha.6 react-native
```

but check what's inside your package.json and watch any warning messages carefully

Answer (score 0):

Try install  react-native-git-upgrade

```
$ npm install -g react-native-git-upgrade
```

and then run

```
$ react-native-git-upgrade
```

for me it works.

Comment: I will give this a try

Answer (score 0):

This error happens when someone upgrade react-native version.

`$ npm install -g react-native-git-upgrade`

`$ npm install react-native@latest --save`

`$ react-native-git-upgrade`

Close all terminals.
Then clear cache. Remove directory ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
In Xcode, Product-> Clean

Then run simulator from Xcode or run code on the attached device again.